# Is it possible to tell nginx to delay a response from a reverse proxied server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rate-limiting

I have an application server sitting behind nginx, and in some cases (e.g. wrong password), I want to intentionally delay the response by 500ms or more.

Implementing this delay in the application server requires a bit of redesign.

Is it possible to somehow tell nginx, via a header, to delay the response?

(I know about the rate limiting as described https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/, but it seems to have some limitations; e.g. it categorizes by IP address so someone with 1000 proxies could bypass this -- correct me if I'm wrong.  I am open to other ideas, of course.)

Comment: Where does the password check happen?

Comment: In the application which is configured as a reverse proxy from nginx.

Comment: I think that would be the best place to sleep a certain time before returning an answer.  But don't forget, wherever you decide to block the response, you're wasting precious resources: server memory, open connections ...  It would cost less to reject the next request from or for that account.

Comment: That's the problem; sleeping on the application service takes out a worker thread so multiple such requests will block the entire application or otherwise increase number of threads -- alternatively it requires a redesign to make certain processes asynchronous -- this is a massive change, which I'd like to avoid as we don't need it anywhere else.  Thus I was asking if there is an nginx based solution.

Comment: I always prefer the simple solutions myself.  What about the application rejecting logins for that account for a small time, increasing with each failed try.  Alternative would be to inform Nginx about the failure, but Nginx would normally block based on IP address.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That's a good solution, much better than stalling the server.  Thanks for the suggestion!